# Multiple background transition CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have an element with multiple (two) backgrounds

```
div
{
    background: url("bg1.png"), url("bg2.png");
    transition: background 1s;
}

div:hover
{
    background-position: 0 -20px, 0 -200px;
}
```

Here, both backgrounds will move in the same time.

How can I have different transition time on them ?

I guess one solution would be to use @keyframes to delay one of the backgrounds animation but I wondered if there was any other way.

Comment: I don't think you can. You are only transitioning one property...albeit with two values.

Comment: I thought so, didn't harm to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/UtcBP/) that might help you.

Relevant CSS:

```
.testdiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Tux-small.png"),
                url("http://www.twitip.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/twitter-button-small.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}
.testdiv:hover {
    background-position: 0 -20px, 0 -200px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I know it can be done with JS, I was only wondering if CSS3 made it possible. Thanks.

Comment: Here's an update - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/UtcBP/1/. There is no JS in the fiddle - I sometimes use the JS box for copy-paste, I just forgot to erase it. The updated fiddle is All CSS

Comment: Thanks, but there is no transition, I would for instance like the upper background to go smooth while the other one should move instantly (or such).

Comment: Here's the update that gives you part of what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/UtcBP/2/. I've looked for quite a while and can't find a pure css solution. Probably need to think about jQuery. edit = I wonder if you could merge two divs together and get what you want.

Comment: Maybe it's different on my computer, but the last value for transition (0.5s) is applied to both background.

I guess that means it is not possible with only CSS. (That was merely to know, I think it is unnecessary to discuss how to do it with JS)

Thanks !